# How far from the correct pronunciations and spellings must one differ to avoid saying God's names?

Tags: halacha, shemos-sacred-names

It's my understanding that there are halachic reasons to avoid saying or writing some of God's Names for no reason. How far from the correct spelling or pronunciations must one deviate to avoid these complications? For example, many people with Ashkenazi pronunciation will say or write E-lokeinu, replacing the ה with a ק or a כּ. Does this "work" in terms of rendering the sacred name profane enough for common usage? Doesn't the new spelling/pronunciation still contain a related, and similarly holy, theonym within the first two letters? Also, there is another Name, the one that starts with a י and ends with a הּ. If one spells or pronounces it ה‎, without the aspiration associated with the mappiq הּ, is this sufficiently different for everyday use?

Comment: what's a "regular hey sound"? please edit to clarify. the only sound a 'hey' makes that i know of is the aspirated "h" sound.

Comment: You seem confused about a mappik. Mappik isn't a special kind of Hey. It's just to pronounce the letter like it's ordinary sound. There is no other way to pronounce a hey. If you don't pronounce any consonant at the end of "Yah" then it's clearly not the same word, like saying "speak" without the "k".

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73619/603  --I remember another answer on this site that quotes the Kaf HaChayim, but I can't find it now